# Linux TCP/IP kernel stack and VFS interaction

Tags: linux-kernel, c, tcp-ip, vfs

I'm reading the Linux kernel implementation of the TCP/IP stack. Everything was ok till I encounter this figure
[image: VFS - Networking subsystems interaction] while reading [TCP/IP architecture, design and implementation in Linux](https://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=0EB7F7C7F594A2DCF795BF0C5197C64D)

As you may see there the author tries to describe the interaction between VFS and the socket layer on Linux. That left me with ton of doubts:

On the image it's shown a socket as a part of a file struct under a particular inode, thing is: that relationship doesn't exist anymore! (and tbh doesn't makes a ton of sense since only netlink and unix domain sockets might have inodes associated but not inet sockets isn't it?). See [struct file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L942) definition; f_dentry dissapeared and while greping you can find

> Documentation/filesystems/porting.rst
> 570: f_dentry is gone; use f_path.dentry, or, better yet, see if you can avoid it

Now same struct above does have a reachable dentry (as mentioned in docs) through **f_path** field but **dentry** is described as a two purpose struct, fist for describing a directory entry and second as a file system directory cache, so even if the relationship had not disappeared (as described in picture) this does not make a lot of sense to me, why to put the socket within an object that is intended to be ephemereal, see [Dcache](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html#directory-entry-cache-dcache) (maybe I'm misunderstanding dentry/dcache?).

Continuing looking at the code you can see [socket struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/net.h#L116) definition. We can see that it still has the old **file** struct as field (makes more sense to clear VFS -> TCP/IP relationship but conserve TCP/IP -> VFS relationship in those directions for the reason above), but, question is, does it really dissapeared? I'm not seeing anything stopping for [fd creation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c#L1669) at any kind of socket, see [sock_map_fd](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c#L481) - [sock_alloc_file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c#L459) - [alloc_file_pseudo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/file_table.c#L255) as well. Also this particular **inode** object socket->file->inode) should be existent only in memory since does not pertain to any device filesystem, but, who is its superblock?, see [indode.sb](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L608).

This is not entirely TCP/IP-VFS interaction exactly, but, I can get an inode either from [file->f_inode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L949) or through [file->f_path->d_inode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/dcache.h#L89), what is the relation between both inodes?.

If someone can help me to understand it would be awesome folks, thanks in advance.

Comment: All sockets (address families) have inodes. This can be clearly seen in ˋ/proc/self/net/tcpˋ with the inode column, as well as when cat'ing a ˋ/proc/$PID/fdinfo/$FDˋ pseudo file. The latter will show in its first line "socket:[#ino]".

Comment: So you are saying that each socket is part of the proc fs, that's weird (to me). Proc fs is built in real time isn't it? and particularly /proc/self inherits the process which intends to read the fs, so what about a socket not actually created with the process reading the fs but let's say systemd like ssh daemons or things like that.

Comment: check out netstat, show socket, or even my lxkns namespace discovery engine. lxkns discovers namespaces also from open file descriptors which it reads from the host's procfs. My fdooze leak checker for Go also dcans the fds in a process procfs view, including sockets, as you can see in the unit tests.

Comment: maybe view the architecture not from the VFS side of things, but from inodes as the tool used for managing resource lifecycles. The VFS doesn't necessarily show all resources as first class citizens: sockets don't show up in directories as themselves (but some other resources, like namespaces can be bind-mounted into the VFS outside of the procfs). Yet sockets and other resources have inodes (look for sockfs IIRC) and are handled using file descriptors. The procfs chooses to make information about sockets visible in some places through pseudo text files; these are not the sockets themselves.